# Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, pagerequestmanager

I have an AJAX TabContainer in update panel which have menus. when I try to switch those menus it never switch the menu stays on same page. 
Following error caught by javascript.
[image]

How to find exact error line number. It wont allow me to debug too..!

Please help!
Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use IE developer tools (Open IE and hit F12).

Make sure to select the Debugger tab in the developer tools window.

[image: IE Developer Tools]

Comment: I tried this too..but cant get the error source and line number at which error occurred. It says: 'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500' any idea?